# How to set image on circular progress bar?

Tags: angular, typescript

[image]

I've followed this [github](https://github.com/Feridum/angular2-circle-progress), the circular progress was find. But...how to set image in circle of circular progress bar?

```
<circle-progress #circleProg1
                   [percent]="25"
                   [boxSize]="400"
                   [radius]="140"
                   [lowColor]="'red'"
                   [middleColor]="'orange'"
                   [interColor]="'#f1c40f'"
                   [highColor]="'#16a085'"
                   [border]="20"
                   [time]="5"
                   (click)="circleProg1.animate()"
  ></circle-progress>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, seems there is no way to add the image , instead you can use

**[`angular-svg-round-progressbar`](https://github.com/crisbeto/angular-svg-round-progressbar)**

and add the css as

```
.round-progress {
    background: url(YourImageHere.png);
    border-radius: 1000px; /* so the image doesn't overflow */
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: I need to try it first. Thanks!